# How to mock/test NestJS service calls to repository?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs, ts-jest, nestjs-typeorm

I have a NestJS service that has a pretty simple method I am trying to write unit tests for

```ts
@Injectable()
export class TestService {

  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(TestEntity)
    private readonly repo: Repository<TestEntity>,
  ) {}

  async getAllTests(acct: AccountEntity): Promise<Array<TestEntity>> {
    try {
      const query = this.repo.createQueryBuilder(DB_TABLE_NAME_TEST);
      query.where({ account: acct.id });

      return await query.getMany();
    } catch (ex) {
      throw new InternalServerErrorException();
    }
  }
}
```

And the tests

```ts
const mockAccount: AccountEntity = {
  id: 'mock-account-id-1234',
  email: 'test@testerson.org',
};

const mockTest: TestEntity = {
  id: '1234-5678-9012',
  account: 'mock-account-id-1234',
  description: 'Test Name',
  testerName: 'Bob Jones',
  testerEmail: 'bob@aol.com',
};

describe('TestService', () => {
  let service: TestService;
  let repo: Repository<TestEntity>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        TestService,
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(TestEntity),
          useValue: {
            create: jest.fn(),
            save: jest.fn(),
            delete: jest.fn(),
            createQueryBuilder: jest.fn(() => ({
              where: jest.fn(),
              getMany: jest.fn(),
              getOne: jest.fn(),
            })),
          },
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get(TestService);
    repo = module.get(getRepositoryToken(TestEntity));
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('getAllTests()', () => {
    it('should successfully get a list of all tests for the provided account', async () => {
      jest.spyOn(repo.createQueryBuilder(DB_TABLE_NAME_TEST), 'where')
      jest.spyOn(repo.createQueryBuilder(DB_TABLE_NAME_TEST), 'getMany').mockResolvedValue([mockTest]);

      expect(repo.createQueryBuilder(DB_TABLE_NAME_TEST).where).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ account: mockAccount.id });
      await expect(service.getAllTests(mockAccount)).resolves.toEqual([mockTest]);
    });

    it('should throw an error when the query fails', async () => {
      jest.spyOn(repo.createQueryBuilder(DB_TABLE_NAME_TEST), 'where').mockImplementation(() => {
        throw new Error();
      });

      jest.spyOn(repo.createQueryBuilder(DB_TABLE_NAME_TEST), 'getMany').mockImplementation(() => {
        throw new Error();
      });

      const result = () => service.getAllTests(mockAccount);
      await expect(result).rejects.toThrow(InternalServerErrorException);
    });
  });
});
```

Both of those tests for the `getAllTests()` method fails with:

```
 FAIL  src/test/test.service.spec.ts
  ● TestService › getAllTests() › should successfully get a list of all tests for the provided account

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: {"account": "mock-account-id-1234"}

    Number of calls: 0

      143 |       jest.spyOn(repo.createQueryBuilder(DB_TABLE_NAME_TEST), 'getMany').mockResolvedValue([mockTest]);
      144 |
    > 145 |       expect(repo.createQueryBuilder(DB_TABLE_NAME_TEST).where).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ account: mockAccount.id });
          |                                                                 ^
      146 |       await expect(service.getAllTests(mockAccount)).resolves.toEqual([mockTest]);
      147 |     });
      148 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (test/test.service.spec.ts:145:65)

  ● TestService › getAllTests() › should throw an error when the query fails

    expect(received).rejects.toThrow()

    Received promise resolved instead of rejected
    Resolved to value: undefined

      157 |
      158 |       const result = () => service.getAllTests(mockAccount);
    > 159 |       await expect(result).rejects.toThrow(InternalServerErrorException);
          |             ^
      160 |     });
      161 |   });
      162 | });

      at expect (../node_modules/expect/build/index.js:113:15)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/test.service.spec.ts:159:13)
```

This seems like it should be pretty straight forward. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first test, you assert the mock.where to have been called *before* calling the service. **Also** every time you call `createQueryBuilder`, you'll get back a **new** `.where` with a new `jest.fn()` tracking the calls to it. What I would suggest you do here is create a separate `const whereMock = jest.fn().mockReturnThis()`  so you can set `where: whereMock` in the `createQueryBuilder` object. This will allow you to access the correct `jest.fn()` when asserting what the `where` has been called with

And in the second test, once again because the `createQueryBuilder` is a `jest.fn()` **every** call to it returns a new object, so your `jest.spyOn` calls are not spying on the same object that the service is using. To get past this, you can create mocks like I suggested for the `whereMock` so they can be referenced directly without having to go through the new object.

Comment: Good point about the service being called after my first `expect` - I actually found and fixed that after I posted this.  Since I am providing my mock object as a value in the `beforeEach`, how do I provide different values on a per-test basis?  Can you give an example of how to do this?

Comment: Also I should note that the additional `expect` for testing the `where` method call is much less important that the `getMany` since that is what returns the data. That's my primary testing concern.

Comment: Nevermind, now I understand and the tests work. thank you!